# Not able to save using simple custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I'm learning custom controllers and facing difficulty in simple save action in Account page. What I'm doing because of changes made to account are not getting saved ?

This is my simple **VF page**

```
<!-- update any record into Database if ID is present using custom Account controller, else save new record  -->
<apex:page controller="cntcustomControllersave" >
<apex:pageMessage severity="Info" />
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageblock >
     <apex:pageblocksection >
        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}" />
         <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Industry}" />
     </apex:pageblocksection>


    <apex:pageblockButtons >
      <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save Acc Details"/>
    </apex:pageblockButtons>
 </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

This is my **Controller**

```
public class cntcustomControllersave {


  public Account acc{

     get{
          Id accId  = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');
          acc =  ( accId== null)? new Account(): [select id, name, industry from Account where Id = : accId];
          return acc;
     }

     set;

   }

    public PageReference save() {

        Try{
              upsert (acc);
            }
         catch(system.dmlException e) 
           {
             Apexpages.AddMessages(e);
              return null;
           }

          return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your messages are not appearing because you are using `<apex:pageMessage>` (singular) rather than `<apex:pageMessages>` (plural). The singular version is for showing a custom message in the Salesforce style, if, for instance, you wanted to set the text explicitly.

Using `<apex:pageMessages>` and your code, I see the error:

> Required fields are missing: [Account Name]

This is because the acc property in the controller has a bug. This code

```
 get{
      Id accId  = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');
      acc =  ( accId== null)? new Account(): [select id, name, industry from Account where Id = : accId];
      return acc;
 }
```

will ALWAYS return a new, blank account when there is no `id` parameter for the page. ALWAYS - i.e. when the page is rendered and you do want a new, blank account, AND when the `save()` method accesses acc, and you really want the account with the user's data.

You should initialize acc in the controller's constructor, and make the acc property much simpler:

```
public class cntcustomControllersave {
    public Account acc { get; set; }

    public cntcustomControllersave(){
        Id accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        acc = (accId == null) ? new Account() : [select id, name, industry from Account where Id = :accId];
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        try {
            upsert (acc);
        } catch(system.DmlException e) {
            Apexpages.AddMessages(e);
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I just saw it and it is working perfectly! So this is bug in getter/setter?

Comment: The bug was in your getter implementation - you were creating a new Account every time the getter was called, so the user's changes were lost before they could be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Curious_Techy

While I've not done the work to copy your code into my own dev org, I can tell you that if you're unable to save the controller, you'll be presented with an error message.

If you use the developer console, and open your file, when you go to save, you'll see the error on the errors tab.

Comment: I 'm expecting error in <apex:pagemessages/> tag in VF but so far .. not getting any error.. thanks !

Comment: You won't see the errors in <apex:pagemessages/> tag if you cannot save the controller.

Comment: You won't see the errors in <apex:pagemessages/> tag if you cannot save the controller.

Comment: I think the problem was that the save() method wasn't working, not that the code wasn't being saved.